# Override all existing traffic routes

Tags: istio

I have an nginx container that handles html content & traffic routing via a VirtualService.

I have a separate maintenance nginx container I want to display (when I'm doing maintnenece) and on this occasion, I want all traffic to be routed to this maintenance container rather than the normal one stated in the first paragraph. I don't really want to have to tweak/patch the original traffic routes so looking for a way to have some form of override traffic routing rule.

From what I have read, the order of rules is based on the creation date so that didn't really help me.

So if anyone has any ideas how I can force all traffic to be routed to a specific "maintenance" service I would really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand setting a version label and work with that.

First create a `DestinationRule` to define your different versions and how they are identified (by labels).

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginx-versions
spec:
  host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: maintenance
    labels:
      version: maintenance
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
```

Next setup your route in the `VirtualService` to point to `v1`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - example.com
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  http:
  - name: nginx-route
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/nginx"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
```

Now you need one `Service` and the two `Deployment`s.

The selector in the service will need to match both deployments. In a normal kubernetes setup this would mean, that traffic would be routed between all workloads of both deployments. But because of istio and the version setup the traffic will only be send to the currently configured version.

The deployment with the maintenance version needs to be labeled with `version: maintenance` and the actual version needs to be labeled with `version: v1`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: nginx
labels:
  app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-maintenance
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: maintenance
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx-maintenance
[...]
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-v1
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx-v1
[...]
```

If you want the traffic to be routed to the maintenance version just change the subset statement in the `VirtalService` and reapply it.

If you want in-cluster traffic always be send to your `v1` version for some reason, you need another `VirtualService` that used the `mesh` gateway. Otherwise cluster internal traffic will be divided between all workload (v1 and maintenance).
Alternatively you could add the mesh gateway and the host to the VirtualService from above, but than cluster internal traffic will always behave like external traffic.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-route-in-cluster
spec:
  hosts:
  - nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
  - mesh
  http:
  - name: nginx-route
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/nginx"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
```

Furthermore you could even use more versions and test updates by sending only a portion of your traffic to the new version.

To get a better understanding and some more ideas about versioning using istio please refere to [this article](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2017/0.1-canary/) (it's actually quite old but the concept is still relevant).